# stop file caching for a process and its children

Tags: linux, caching, process, limit

I have a process that reads thousands of small files ONE TIME. The cached data is not needed after this. The process proceeds at full speed until most memory is consumed by the file cache and then it slows down. I don't understand the slowdown, since freeing cache memory and allocating space for the next file should be a matter of microseconds. Hard page faults also increase when this threshold is reached. The OS is vanilla Ubuntu 16.04.

I would like to limit the file caching for this process only.

This is a user process, so using a privileged shell command to purge the cache is not a solution. Using fadvise on a per-file level is not a solution, since the files are being read my multiple library programs depending on the file type.

What I need is a process-level option: do not cache, or set a low size limit like 100 MB. I have searched for this and found nothing. Is this really the case? Seems like something big that is missing.

Any insight on the apparent memory management performance issue?

Comment: If the files/buffers are not dirtied, the caching will not cost you anything. Whenever memory gets scarse, the buffers can be reclaimed for other purposes (either as work memory, or for other buffers) without additional cost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the strict answer to your question. If you are `mmap`-ing your files, the way to do this is using `madvise()` and `MADV_DONTNEED`:

```
   MADV_DONTNEED
          Do not expect access in the near future.  (For the time being,
          the  application is finished with the given range, so the ker‐
          nel  can  free  resources  associated  with  it.)   Subsequent
          accesses  of pages in this range will succeed, but will result
          either in reloading of the memory contents from the underlying
          mapped  file  (see  mmap(2))  or zero-fill-on-demand pages for
          mappings without an underlying file.
```

There is to my knowledge no way of doing it with files that are simply opened, read (using `read()` or similar) and closed.

However, it sounds to me like this is not in fact the issue. Are you sure it's buffer / cache that is growing here, and not something else? (e.g. perhaps you are reading them into RAM and not freeing that RAM, or not closing them, or similar)

You can tell by doing:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

if you don't get all the memory back, then it's your program which is leaking something.

Comment: None of the above. Please read the post more carefully. The disk cache is the only thing consuming memory, and it goes back to "normal" when the volume with all the recently read files is unmounted.

Comment: And if you try the `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` does that also make things go back to normal?

Comment: That command requires root user. Please re-read the problem description and my final note below.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced there is no way to stop file caching on a per-process level. The program must have direct control over file I/O, with access to the file descriptors so that madvise() can be used. You cannot do this if library functions are doing all the file reading and you are not willing to modify them. This does look like a design gap that should be filled.

HOWEVER: My assertion of some performance issue with memory management was wrong. The reason for the process slow-down as the file cache grows and free memory shrinks was something else: disk seek distances were growing during the process. Other tests have verified that allocating memory does not significantly slow down as the file cache grows and free memory shrinks.